# M2 - Search for translations

Tags: store-view, localisation, translate

I need to translate some notification messages, but I can't find the correct string to translate... I've installed a extension for a dutch language pack, but where can I find the files where the translations are stored?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to find the closest element class or ID and search the codebase for that, that should return the correct template and from there you can navigate to the string.

Or alternatively search for the string you are seeing on the frontend and hopefully it'll return a translation for it, and from there you can search for the original string.